# Merge [immutablejs] into [immutable.js]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

1. [immutablejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutablejs) has 3 questions tagged
2. [immutable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutable.js) has 422 questions tagged
3. [immutablejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutablejs) only has a wiki because I was confused by the similar tags names.

Both tags are talking about the same repository and there should just be a single tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I retagged the 3 questions in that tag, and also improved each question by fixing the formatting, the grammar, the rewording of the post and the title.

Since there are no more questions with [immutablejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutablejs), the tag will be gone at 3 AM UTC. If you notice it reappearing, you may want to suggest a synonym, instead of retagging manually again.